# Processing credit cards in React/Node using only open source tech

Tags: node.js, reactjs, payment, credit-card

If you go out and look for how to process credit cards online, you will continuously get sent towards Paypal or Stripe (which are great options!).  These have great features, including nice client UIs, but they don't always fit the problem domain.

I need to accept credit card payments to replace in-person payments for a business, which means no extra fees outside of what credit cards already charge.  This is for both Canada and the USA.

Is there an established "best pick" for open source frameworks for handling credit card payments in Node and React?

Comment: You need a payment gateway that can talk to other payment processors.  IOW, you need Stripe (you can use their REST API without their UI).

Comment: Stripe has some open-source for you to add on react native easily - https://github.com/tipsi/tipsi-stripe

Comment: @SLaks Appreciate the feedback.  I definitely realize we need a payment gateway, but Stripe costs significantly more than a typical in-person payment gateway.  I need to find a way to have equivalent transaction fees to in-person payments (which rules out Stripe)

Comment: @Chris: Card-not-present transactions are inherently more expensive than card-present transactions; I believe because of increased risk of fraud.  You are not likely to find such a thing.

Comment: @SLaks Hmm, I'll have to double-check, but I'm 95% sure that many online booking systems don't have extra fees beyond credit card payment gateway fees, as an example

Answer (score 0):

**To be clear, I am showing you one merchant that you can use. Whichever merchant your client is using now to take credit card payments will most likely have a REST API to use.**

Most merchant service will have some sort of an API you can use. Since we do not know which merchant you are planning on using I will show you a popular one.

I have used [authorize.net](https://www.authorize.net/solutions/merchantsolutions/onlinemerchantaccount/?gclid=EAIaIQobChMIoIT2osaO1wIVE5N-Ch0ldQtzEAAYASAAEgJlj_D_BwE) a lot in my career. They have a REST API you can consume to handle payments for your clients. The API has a SDK you can download for whichever language you want to use.

[The developer portal is here.](https://developer.authorize.net/api/)

[You can see popular language examples here.](https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/index.html)

When you go to that last link click on code examples and pick the 
language you want to see.

[image]

[Here is the SDK repo for Node.js.](https://github.com/AuthorizeNet/sdk-node)

Find more SDKs on git and use them in your app!

Let me know if you have anymore questions.

Comment: Got it, thanks.  So in summary, the fact that they are already taking credit card payments in person means they already have a gateway provider.  That gateway provider should also have a REST API that we can use as a payment processor, rather than going through something like Stripe and incurring added fees?

Comment: @Chris exactly! There is always the chance they might not have an API but I doubt it. Try an find out which merchant service they are using and then go from there. On the other hand, if they do not have an API and it becomes a huge pain to deal with them, then just use authorize.net. I have had companies use a credit card merch internally then authorize net for the website. I hope this helps! If it does please accept and upvote!

Comment: Authorize.Net's APIs and client libraries are poorly designed and a real pain to use.  I strongly recommend Stripe instead.

Comment: The point of this is not to recommend an API, the point of this is to show that a merchant service will have an API. For example, if the client is using Chase Bank or Bank of America than they can use their resources to make the app. Also Authorize.net has a great API with tons of documentation, great examples and a huge community. Stripe is very simple to use but does not give you a fraction of the capabilities. In the end use the right tool for the job, not a hammer.